# Android:How can i make an AutoCompleteTextView to pass the text from a website and show me the results

Tags: java, android, url, web, autocompletetextview

How can i make an `AutoCompletTextView`  to pass the text from a website and show me the results in `ListView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After parsing the webservice data you will get results into an array.

Let's say you are getting result into array named `resultData` then use below code.

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(viewAutoComplete,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultData);
autoCompleteText.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Always Welcome Dear !!